# How to find elements in the active area that is visible on the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to determine elements in the visible region of Div?**

There are 2 div within main div.
The wrapper div contains many child div with overflow property.
On scrolling the document div i need to find out the visible 
children div in the wrapper.

Below is HTML structure

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="comment"></div>      
  <div class="comment"></div>
  <div class="comment"></div>
  <div class="comment"></div>
  <div class="comment"></div>
  </div>
<div class="document"></div>
</div>

  Is there any possibility for finding the number of visible div in the window?
```

Comment: Are you talking about your `window`? Like, the active area that is visible on the page and not the `document`?

Comment: I'm with ya. Gimme a sec

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('wrapperdivselector').find("div:visible");
```

for length:

```
 $('wrapperdivselector').find("div:visible").length;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zDyR/)**

Answer (score 1):

use :visible try this

```
$('.orginalDiv1>.waprrer div:visible').someCommand()
```

or

```
$('.orginalDiv1>.waprrer').find('div:visible').lenght()
```